# OnDrawCell Center Text StringGrid - Delphi

Tags: delphi, tstringgrid

I'm trying to get the text in my StringGrid to center. After some research I came up with this function posted by someone else here that when used on DefaultDraw:False should work.

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid2DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
 Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  S: string;
  SavedAlign: word;
begin
  if ACol = 1 then begin  // ACol is zero based
   S := StringGrid1.Cells[ACol, ARow]; // cell contents
    SavedAlign := SetTextAlign(StringGrid1.Canvas.Handle, TA_CENTER);
    StringGrid1.Canvas.TextRect(Rect,
      Rect.Left + (Rect.Right - Rect.Left) div 2, Rect.Top + 2, S);
    SetTextAlign(StringGrid1.Canvas.Handle, SavedAlign);
  end;
end;
```

However if I set DefaultDraw:False, the StringGrid just appears glitchey.

The lines in the function that fill the StringGrid with  text is

```
Sg.RowCount := Length(arrpos);
for I := 0 to (Length(arrpos) - 1) do
 begin
   sg.Cells[0,i] := arrpos[i];
   sg.Cells[1,i] := arrby[i];
 end;
```

arrpos and arrby are arrays of string. sg is the StringGrid.

I need after that has been executing the text to appear in the center on the cell.

**UPDATE**

For those suffering from similar problems one of the key issues with this piece of code is if the if statement

```
if ACol = 1 then begin
```

That line means it will only run the code for column 1 e.g. the second column since StringGrid is 0 based. You can safely remove the if statement and it will execute and work WITHOUT having to disable default drawing.

Comment: I've just tried your code and it works fine. (Delphi 5 and 10 @Win7)

Comment: The problem with the code was that the procedure is for StringGrid2 however in the code it's listed as StringGrid1. Another reason I hate delphi auto-complete.However I THINK Dorin Duminica's method is more efficient anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this works in my test

```
procedure TForm1.sgDrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer; Rect: TRect;
  State: TGridDrawState);
var
  LStrCell: string;
  LRect: TRect;
begin
  LStrCell := sg.Cells[ACol, ARow]; // grab cell text
  sg.Canvas.FillRect(Rect); // clear the cell
  LRect := Rect; 
  LRect.Top := LRect.Top + 3; // adjust top to center vertical
  // draw text
  DrawText(sg.Canvas.Handle, PChar(LStrCell), Length(LStrCell), LRect, DT_CENTER);
end;
```