# right justify delphi stringgrid column but keep themed drawingstyle

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, tstringgrid

I am using delphi 2010 for a project with a stringgrid. I want some columns of the grid to be right justified. [I understand how I can do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720255/ondrawcell-center-text-stringgrid-delphi) with defaultdrawing set to false.

I would like, however, to keep the runtime theme shading for the grid, if possible. Is there a way to right justify a column with defaultdrawing enabled, or at least duplicate the code in the onDrawCell event to imitate the runtime theme shading?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use an interposer class and override the DrawCell method, check this sample

```
type
  TStringGrid = class(Grids.TStringGrid)
   protected
    procedure DrawCell(ACol, ARow: Longint; ARect: TRect; AState: TGridDrawState); override;
  end;    

  TForm79 = class(TForm)
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
  end;

var
  Form79: TForm79;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TStringGrid }

procedure TStringGrid.DrawCell(ACol, ARow: Integer; ARect: TRect; AState: TGridDrawState);
var
  s : string;
  LDelta : integer;
begin
  if (ACol=1) and (ARow>0) then
  begin
    s     := Cells[ACol, ARow];
    LDelta := ColWidths[ACol] - Canvas.TextWidth(s);
    Canvas.TextRect(ARect, ARect.Left+LDelta, ARect.Top+2, s);
  end
  else
  Canvas.TextRect(ARect, ARect.Left+2, ARect.Top+2, Cells[ACol, ARow]);
end;

procedure TForm79.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StringGrid1.Cells[0,0]:='title 1';
  StringGrid1.Cells[1,0]:='title 2';
  StringGrid1.Cells[2,0]:='title 3';

  StringGrid1.Cells[0,1]:='normal text';
  StringGrid1.Cells[1,1]:='right text';
  StringGrid1.Cells[2,1]:='normal text';
end;
```

And the result

[image]